# how to use two plural words in one sentences correctly

Tags: word-usage, plural-forms, noun-phrases

I just confused about how can I use two plural words in one sentence.

For example,

1- The multivariate **dependencies** **structures** between two variables are complex.

2- The multivariate **dependency** **structures** between two variables are complex.

*Dependence* means the relationship between variables (say, age and blood pressure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better if you look at this as a single [noun phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) rather than "two words in plural."

The main word in this noun phrase is "structure". It can then be put into plural irrespective of what its modifier (dependency/dependencies) is.

A structure is a relationship between multiple components. Thus, the singular form of your noun phrase is "dependencies structure" (in the computer science sense of "dependency" of "can't install A until you install/update X, Y, and Z"—each of which is a single dependency (just making this caveat in case anyone confuses a software dependency with uncountable "dependence")).

I'm finding this phrase, e.g., [here](http://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/19.1/ug-editor/topics/xml-schema-component-dependencies.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies), and [here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=RfW5rC9Rn84C&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=%22dependencies+structure%22&source=bl&ots=3quagQoX8c&sig=UCF97wctuBos9c_a1YmAgYezYkQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib0oCvocPZAhVEDSwKHeC2DbE4ChDoAQg5MAY#v=onepage&q=%22dependencies%20structure%22&f=false) (this last example has it as "dependencies' structure", but there is really no need for an apostrophe, as the word "dependencies" easily becomes a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) (an adjective-fied noun).

Thus, the plural of this will be "dependencies structures."